# How to combine multiple php functions in single statement?

Tags: php

What am trying to do is to get the JPG file location from the below function.

Whenever I try to execute this it throws the error "file not found", is there a syntax problem?  If so, what should be the syntax to integrate multiple functions like this be?

```
$handle = imagecreatefromjpeg($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/cts/'.$tempDir.'.jpg');
```

Comment: where you put the value of $tempdir??? is it a file name??if not where is the file name?

Comment: not clear enough. please elaborate with details

Comment: What do you mean by "multiple functions"? The only function used in that code is `imagecreatefromjpeg`

Comment: Can you confirm file_exists($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/cts/'.$tempDir.'.jpg'); ? Else check output from echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/cts/'.$tempDir.'.jpg';

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$handle = imagecreatefromjpeg($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/cts/'.$tempDir.'.jpg');
```

Or this:

```
$handle = imagecreatefromjpeg('cts/'.$tempDir.'.jpg');
```